How to allocate a GPU for snakemake 8 execution on GKE
I'm trying to execute snakemake 8 on a GKE GPU node pool however the resource parameters in the docs don't appear to trigger any kind of autoscaling through Kubernetes.
According to the docs there are a number of locations you can put the GPU resources flag
snakemake --snakefile workflow/snakefile_stage3_totalvi.smk \
          --executor kubernetes \
          --software-deployment-method conda \
          --default-storage-provider gcs \
          --default-storage-prefix $BUCKET \
          --storage-gcs-project $PROJECT \
          --set-resources totalvi_train.smk:gpu=1 \
          --jobs 1

Ive also tried resources: gpu=1 and default-resources: gpu=1 as well as setting the resources: gpu=1 directly in the rule itself.
Changing the mem and cores resources does in fact trigger the respective node pools so the problem is gpu specific.

Make sure that the GPU nodes in the GKE node pool are properly provisioned with NVIDIA device plugins,which makes  GPU’s available to kubernetes.Install  NVIDIA plugin if it's not installed yet. After this your GPU resources will be available to kubernetes pods and snakemake can use them.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.
